# Unable to write dataframe to azure cosmo db

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I am unable to write data to ****cosmos db**** using *databricks spark cluster*. However, I tried all the links and solutions in Stackoverflow and Github and tried all the possible jars with about every version.

The error stack is:

> 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

> com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Offer.getContent()Lorg/json/JSONObject;
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBConnection.getCollectionThroughput(CosmosDBConnection.scala:163)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBSpark$.save(CosmosDBSpark.scala:173)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBSpark$.save(CosmosDBSpark.scala:501)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:72)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:70)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:88)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:180)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:131)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:114)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:690)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:690)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:228)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:85)k

My code is :

```
import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time.format._

import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBSpark
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val configMap = Map(
  "Endpoint" -> "MY-CONNECTION-ENDPOINT",
  "Masterkey" -> "MY-KEY",
  "Database" -> "Families",
  "Collection" -> "Families","Upsert"->"true")

val config = Config(configMap)
val df = spark.range(5).select(col("id").cast("string").as("value"))
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).cosmosDB(config)
```